# Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB on Camera permission request

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I am getting the following Error log on Fabric,

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.checkPermission(ActivityManagerNative.java:5157)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.checkPermission(ContextImpl.java:1610)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.checkPermission(ContextWrapper.java:665)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.checkPermission(ContextWrapper.java:665)
   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContextCompat.java:430)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.checkCameraPermissionGranded(LaunchActivity.java:275)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(LaunchActivity.java:296)
   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4178)
   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:394)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.requestCameraPermission(LaunchActivity.java:289)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(LaunchActivity.java:299)
   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4178)
   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:394)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.requestCameraPermission(LaunchActivity.java:289)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(LaunchActivity.java:299)
   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4178)
   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:394)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.requestCameraPermission(LaunchActivity.java:289)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(LaunchActivity.java:299)
   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4178)
   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:394)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.requestCameraPermission(LaunchActivity.java:289)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(LaunchActivity.java:299)
   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4178)
   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:394)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.requestCameraPermission(LaunchActivity.java:289)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(LaunchActivity.java:299)
   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4178)
   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:394)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.requestCameraPermission(LaunchActivity.java:289)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(LaunchActivity.java:299)
   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4178)
   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:394)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.requestCameraPermission(LaunchActivity.java:289)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(LaunchActivity.java:299)
   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4178)
   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:394)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.requestCameraPermission(LaunchActivity.java:289)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(LaunchActivity.java:299)
   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4178)
   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:394)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.requestCameraPermission(LaunchActivity.java:289)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(LaunchActivity.java:299)
   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4178)
   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:394)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.requestCameraPermission(LaunchActivity.java:289)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(LaunchActivity.java:299)
   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4178)
   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:394)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.requestCameraPermission(LaunchActivity.java:289)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(LaunchActivity.java:304)
   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:4178)
   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:394)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.requestLocationPermission(LaunchActivity.java:284)
   at ts.shidhin.net.LaunchActivity.onResume(LaunchActivity.java:247)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1287)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7015)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4210)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4323)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1865)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is my Code,

**Button Click**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
          case R.id.btnTakePhoto:
            if (!checkCameraPermissionGranded())
                requestCameraPermission();
            else 
                 takePicture();
            break;
    }
}
```

**Function** `checkCameraPermissionGranded()`

```
private boolean checkCameraPermissionGranded() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(LaunchActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(LaunchActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(LaunchActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

**Function** `requestCameraPermission()`

```
    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LaunchActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Constants.CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

**Function** `onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == Constants.CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (checkCameraPermissionGranded())
            takePicture();
        else {
            requestCameraPermission();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: requestCameraPermission function is causing a recursion

Comment: So we need to remove requestCameraPermission(); from onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: not necessarily, you could just fix the function :) Other people give you a great examples how to do that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are looping on the permissionsPopup.
Your method should look something like this.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Constants.CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                takePicture();
            } else {
                //camera permission denied
                show an explaining message to tell the user why you need that permission
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

You can also do this (the more complete approach)

```
private boolean checkCameraPicturePermissions() {
    canAccessCamera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    canReadExternal = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    canWriteExternal = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if(!canAccessCamera) {
        permissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }
    if(!canReadExternal) {
        permissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if(!canWriteExternal) {
        permissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }

    if (!permissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        requestPermissions(permissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[permissionsNeeded.size()]), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA_PICTURE);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

btnCameraAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(checkCameraPicturePermissions()) {
                    onTakePhoto();
            }

        }
    });

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA_PICTURE: {
            Map<String, Boolean> permissionsMap = new HashMap<>();
            permissionsMap.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, true);
            permissionsMap.put(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, true);
            permissionsMap.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, true);

            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                    permissionsMap.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                }

                canAccessCamera = permissionsMap.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

                if (permissionsMap.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        && permissionsMap.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        && permissionsMap.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                } else {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                            || shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            || shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        rationale(getString(R.string.warning_rationale_permissions));
                    } else {
                        explain(getString(R.string.mandatory_permissions));
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        }

        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

private void rationale(String value) {
    try {
        InformationPopup informationPopup = InformationPopup.newInstance(getString(R.string.warning_title), value, getString(R.string.action_ok), null);
        informationPopup.mListener = new InformationPopup.InformationActionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onButtonLeft(InformationPopup dialog) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        };
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

private void explain(String value) {
    try {
        ConfirmationPopup confirmationPopup = ConfirmationPopup.newInstance(
                getString(R.string.warning_title),
                value,
                getString(R.string.action_no),
                getString(R.string.action_yes), null);
        confirmationPopup.setCancelable(true);
        confirmationPopup.mListener = new ConfirmationPopup.ConfirmationActionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onButtonLeft(ConfirmationPopup dialog) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonRight(ConfirmationPopup dialog) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getContext().getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonRight(ConfirmationPopup dialog, Object object) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonRight(ConfirmationPopup dialog, int index) {

            }
        };
        confirmationPopup.show(getFragmentManager(), "RationalePermissionPopup");
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

ConfirmationPopup and InformationPopup are inheriting DialogFragment, but you can create a regular one. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

that because user did not allow for that permission on  onRequestPermissionsResult you check again and ask for permission 
you should check if your permission not granted disable the feature or ask it when user request that feature.

Android give option to user for don't ask again.

you should change it like this

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[]permissions, int[] grantResults) {
if (requestCode == Constants.CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (checkCameraPermissionGranded())
        takePicture();
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "you can`t use that feature", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}}
```